# How to revert file to previous version

Tags: git

Let's say I'm working on branch A and I merged some changes from branch B.
Branch B has a file named setup.sh and I work on branch A and modify the setup.sh file and commit it and later perform let's say 3 different commits on other files of branch A.

Now I realise that I should not be making the changes in setup.sh file. I want to revert back to the branch B version of setup.sh. Obvious solution is git checkout and git commit, but it shows file modified by me in git blame. I do not want that. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert *to* a particular version of the file, you must make a new commit that contains that version of that file (along with its version of every other file, just like any other commit).

> Obvious solution is git checkout and git commit, but it shows file modified by me in git blame.

That will always be the case, because `git blame` assigns the ownership of each line in a file based on the difference between each snapshot.  That is, we are given the fact that we have a series of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

where the branch name `branch` tells Git that the *last* commit is commit `H`, and commit `H` tells Git that the *previous* commit is commit `G`, with commit `G` telling Git that the previous commit is commit `F`, and so on.  What `git blame` does is extract the file from commit `H`, then extract the same file from commit `G`.  Where the lines match, the ownership moves from `H` to `G`, but we're not done yet.  Where the lines *don't* match, the ownership is at `H`.

Now, if we're at `G`, `git blame` extracts the file from commit `G` and again from commit `F`.  Where the lines match, the ownership moves back to `F`, and where they don't, the ownership stays at `G`.

Once we're at `F`, Git extracts the file from the parent of `F`, and repeats this whole process.

Eventually, each line has an assigned commit, and that's what you see to the left of the line.

This means that *no matter how you restore the file to the old commit*, it's *you* that restored the file, and `git blame` will stop there.  To keep going, you must run a second `git blame` that says *starting from before my commit, look backwards the way you always do* and now `git blame` will assign the lines to earlier commits.  **Git starts at an end and works backwards** and if you want it to start at an end that comes before *your* commit, you simply start it there, instead of at the current commit (or the current working tree copy, which is where we really have `git blame` start, most of the time).

Comment: (Correct me if I am wrong) If I do not want the git blame to pick me, there's no way other than modifying all the commits between the latest commit and the commit which changed the file.

Comment: You literally *can't* change existing commits. You *can* copy all the old commits to new (slightly different, improved) ones, and then ask everyone to stop using the old commits and start using your new ones instead. That's the only way to make it such that you're not the author of a change, and it's generally called "rewriting history". There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this, it's just a pain, and other people may not take your replacement commits.